# Facebook API, Login with Facebook not working on IE only

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to implement a "Login with Facebook" using the Open Graph API. So far this works on FF, Chrome, Safari, but not IE. Testing on IE9.

On IE, I get the Facebook dialog box to login. I can successfully login to Facebook, but then nothing happens. On other browsers, the page redirects and the fb user data is stored to a databse.

I tried both FB doctypes on separate occasions as well, with no luck.

```
xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
```

Edit: I removed the FB.api stuff just to include an alert box for testing. Works on everything but IE still.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId   : '<?php echo $AppID; ?>',
        channelUrl : '//www.mysite.net/channel.php', // Channel File
        oauth   : true,
        status  : true, // check login status
        cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
    });

  };

function fb_login(){
    FB.login(function(response) {

        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            //console.log(response); // dump complete info
            access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken; //get access token
            user_id = response.authResponse.userID; //get FB UID

            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert(response.id);
            });

        } else {
            //user hit cancel button
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    }, {
        scope: 'email,publish_actions'
    }
    );
}
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Comment: important: please specify which version(s) of IE you're testing with.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder... using IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing/commenting out your console.log() areas of the code, I know it's crazy, but last time I tried those in IE, they were complaining about cannot call log on undefined... I wish IE would catch up with the times.

If anything, just give it a shot, it's definitely worth a try for a potentially simple fix. Please believe I know it sounds silly, but it's been the source of IE bugs for me in the past!

Comment: :) I'm telling you, IE deserves to no longer exist for being so far behind the trend like that. I'm really happy to hear it worked for you :D Just an additional unfortunate note, NEVER go into production with those logs implemented, or IE will eat your website's bwainz

Comment: @BryanMoyles, while IE may be not the best browser there is no excuse for calling `console.log` where `console` is not defined, `console` is functionality provided by browser in case of IE it's only defined while Developers Tools opened.